# Jquery validator default error messages in multiple languages

Tags: jquery, validation, localization

I have the following code to change default error messages using jQuery Validation plugin:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is mandatory."
});
```

This works fine, but i want to set default error messages in English and French, how can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible answer, but I don't know if this is the best way to do it. I am checking for the string `fr` in the URL to determine the language.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/fr/')!=-1) {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "Ce champ est obligatoire."
    });
} else {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "This field is mandatory."
    });
}
```

Obviously this would only work if you have `/fr/` somewhere in your URL